# Лесник и лесничий

Tags: значение-слов

Однажды в книге мне попалась информация о том, что лесник и лесничий - это совершенно разные вещи. Конечно, не настолько разные, как "пожарник" и "пожарный", но все-таки.
Я сейчас точно не вспомню, но, мол, кто-то из них заведует только участком леса, а кто-то начальник над всеми остальными.
Правда это или вымысел автора?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сейчас **лесничий** - это должность, говоря понятным термином - директор лесничества. **Лесник** - один из его подчинённых - простой работник в лесничестве. Лесничий - человек с высшим образованием, лесник - уровень ПТУ. Это официальные должности.

Answer (score 1):

Слова *лесник* и *лесничий* являлись с давних пор  синонимами, как видно из Словаря 1789-94. Приведено второе значение (лесник - торговец лесом), но оно вышло из употребления в советские времена по вполне понятным  причинам. Я думаю, слова различаются в наше время по статусу: лесник - обычный, рядовой работник леса; лесничий - бери выше, ответственный специалист с полномочиями. Лесничество - большая контора все же, а лесники, те сидят на дальних кордонах, лосей пересчитывают.
[image]

Comment: ПОЛЕСОВЩИК (сторож леса) — Толковый словарь Ушакова.
Слово широко известно по портрету кисти И.Крамского

Answer (score 1):

> Однажды в книге мне попалась информация о том, что лесник и лесничий - это совершенно разные вещи. Конечно, не настолько разные, как "пожарник" и "пожарный", но все-таки.

Да в общем-то почти такие же. 
Лесничий изначально - должность (сравните городовой, городничий, поверенный, умолномоченный...), и, судя по всему, не последняя в иерархии... А лесником могли назвать кого угодно, вплоть до простого обитателя хижины в лесу. Вот и лесник-лесоторговец непонятно как примешался. Лесничим-то его не назовут.